# Nuxt JS plugin doesn't run on each page change unless full reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working in a Nuxt JS 2 project and have created a `session.js` file loaded with the following:

```js
export default function ({ app, context }, inject) {
  console.log('load session')
}
```

When I do a full page reload the console.log will run, but when changing to a new page it doesn't trigger unless I fully reload the page.

What am I missing to make it run on each page change, this is how it's loaded

```js
{ mode: 'client', src: '~/plugins/utils/tracking.js' }
```

Comment: Aren't you looking for a client side global middleware here? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#middleware

Comment: You need to use middlewares for this task

Answer (score 0):

You must config for plugin on both sides (client and server) {src: '~/plugins/utils/tracking.js'} OR config inject then use in ssr Hooks (validate , asyncData, fetch)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use both a plugin and middleware (as far as I've been able to see).

If you use only middleware then it won't run on hard refresh but will on all subsequent route changes.
If you use only a plugin - it will only run on instantiation of the app.